# I have some trouble with replacing a word AND a special character with whitespace, using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is my code at the moment:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\bReactionDB\b/i',' ', $title_matches[1]);
```

The input text = "It Begins! | ReactionDB"

In addition to "ReactionDB", I want it to replace the character "|" with nothing/whitespace.

I've searched for hours and I'm finding no solution, anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a second call to `preg_replace`:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\bReactionDB\b/i',' ', $title_matches[1]);
$title = preg_replace('/\|/', '', $title);
```

Note that you need to escape `|` as it is a special character.